# "s3cmd get" rewrites local files

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

Trying to download **S3** directory to local machine using **s3cmd**. I'm using the command:

```
s3cmd sync --skip-existing s3://bucket_name/remote_dir ~/local_dir
```

But if I restart downloading after interruption **s3cmd** doesn't skip existing local files downloaded earlier and rewrites them. What is wrong with the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use boto-rsync instead.  https://github.com/seedifferently/boto_rsync

It correctly syncs only new/changed files from s3 to the local directory.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem and found the solution in comment # 38 from William Denniss there http://s3tools.org/s3cmd-sync

If you have:

```
$s3cmd sync —verbose s3://mybucket myfolder
```

Change it to:

```
$s3cmd sync —verbose s3://mybucket/ myfolder/   # note the trailing slash
```

Then, the MD5 hashes are compared and everything works correctly! —skip-existing works as well.

To recap, both —skip-existing and md5 checks won’t happen if you use the first command, and both work if you use the second (I made a mistake in my previous post, as I was testing with 2 different directories).